# NGINX - /etc/nginx/conf.d is empty

Tags: nginx

I'm working with *Nginx From Beginner to Pro*. The book affirms that:

> The /etc/nginx/conf.d folder contains two files, default.conf and
>   example_ssl.conf .

but when I open my  /etc/nginx/conf.d then make the `list` command I have nothing but just some dots like `.. .` which appears and are impossible to handle -neither read or open. So I'm wondering what it happens and why I haven't my files appears in the directory. After having made some searches on web I have found nothing relevant to me.
Also it's impossible to create neither a folder or file in this directory.

Currently I have create an another folder and probably will use it to insert some custom configuration.

Comment: try looking in `/etc/nginx/sites-available`

Comment: there is a `default` file effectively

Answer (score -1):

Today, I also fell into the same issue.

When I was trying to fetch this file using FileZilla, it was not showing up.
But then I logged in through Putty and ran the command

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

The file got opened up with all its contents.

I hope this helps others.

PS: we should not try to alter this file at beginner level.
I had to find it only to increase the hash_bucket_limit inside http object. (Because the length of my domain name regex was larger than default limit).

Comment: According to O'Reilly's "NGINX Cookbook" `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` is a directory, not a file. And so it is on my computer. I just installed NGINX (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) and the folder is empty. There are no files.